# How to extending a class in another file

Tags: php, oop

So I have been doing some OOP and I hit a snag. I'm trying to extend a class in another PHP file. The extended classes should load dynamically. I got it set up like this:

**bootstrap.php** file:

```
<?php
class bootstrap{

    public $lang;
    public $page;
    public $action;
    public $id;
    public $message;

    public function __construct() {
       $this->buildPage();
    }

    public function buildPage() {       
        if($this->page == 'home'){
            require_once CONTR . 'view.php';
            new view($this->lang, $this->page, $this->action, $this->id, $this->message);
        }
    }
}
```

and the **view.php** file:

```
class view extends bootstrap{

    public $lang;
    public $page;
    public $action;
    public $id;
    public $message;

    public function __construct($lang, $page, $action, $id, $message) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang = $lang;
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->action = $action; 
        $this->id = $id; 
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->showPage();
    }

    public function showPage() {
        require_once VIEW . 'header.php';

        //echo VIEW . 'header.php';

        //prepare SQL statements
        $page = $this->page;
        $name = "name_" . $this->lang;

        //SQL statement
        $selectdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE $name = '$page'");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($selectdata);

        //Echo content
        if($result["content_$this->lang"] == NULL){
            echo "no content";
        } else {
            echo $result["content_$this->lang"];
        }


        //Debugging
        echo '<br>' . $this->lang;
        echo '<br>' . $this->page;
        echo '<br>' . $name;
        echo '<br>' . $page;

        require_once VIEW . 'footer.php';
    }
}
```

--> Index.php

```
require('front/config.php');
require('front/bootstrap.php');

 $site = new bootstrap();
```

After doing this I tried to call the view class through the bootstrap class by using extends.

I have been trying lots of different things but I think I am quite close. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this one?
The showpage function does actually work when I put it in the bootstrap class, but when I put it in the view class, nothing works.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what class is the first file?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Do you `require` the parent class `bootstrap` in the subclass `view`?

Comment: The class name in of the first class is bootstrap. And i would need the view class to use the bootstrap class to render a page depending on the URL. I wrote a function that does just that and it works fine. However, when i call the view class in the bootstrap class, nothing works.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense for me do you know what inheritance actually is? View inherits from bootstrap and at the same time you call the constructor of view from bootstrap. Looks pretty strange to me.

Comment: Like I said, I tried many different things. And yes, I do somewhat know what inheritence is.

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve with `extends`. And are there any error messages or what means "nothing works"?

Comment: Just a blank page, no errors. Because the function doesn't load the view class. I'm trying to write the actual function that builds the page, in another file (that gets the data from a database and mold it into the actual content of the page). I'm doing this so i can build a system of sorts and get the data from the database depending on the page that is requested.

Comment: I would remove the extends because it makes no sense. Then try to check if the view class exists with [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't seem to work. The class doesn't seem to exist. Another reason why I use extends, I forgot to mention that, is that there are a few functions in the bootstrap class that build up the menu and such. So that way, if understand correctly, the view class will inherit those by using extends. That way I don't need to rewrite those functions.

Comment: So to get this straight.. You've require_once('bootstrap.php'); and require_once('view.php');  Then loaded the class Bootstrap then  loaded the class View. Correct?

Comment: I edited my question for what I did.